# Website renders like desktop on mobile, only when first loaded or is refreshed

Tags: responsive-design, next.js, media-queries, mobile-website, chakra-ui

I have created a website that uses media queries and is responsive when tested from the Dev tools in browser. However it reverts back to its desktop-like state on reloading. If i click on a link that redirects me to another page, it is displays the second page perfectly as expected. Same for when i go "back". The homepage is now magically responsive.

[View the issue : ]https://reach-tech-interns-page1.vercel.app/

Upon opening on mobile, this link doesn't seem responsive. But click on testimonials and go back, and the homepage is now responsive. If I reload, the mobile site breaks again.

I used Next.js and Chakra UI.

[Github Code:] https://github.com/inferno080/Reach-Tech-Interns-Page

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This is my viewport in _app,js

```<meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1"
        />```

Most similar problems I read online were because of this tag, but I have added it and it still doesnt work. There isnt anything about this bug in nextjs or chakraUI docs. Nor have I encountered my exact same issue anywhere before

Comment: I also thought it was weird because my website is responsive, but only when i follow the steps mentioned above (navigating to another page and going back)

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with Chakra UI's useMediaQuery() hook. Writing a custom hook solved this issue

```
const useMediaQuery = (query) => {
  const [matches, setMatches] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const media = window.matchMedia(query);
    if (media.matches !== matches) {
      setMatches(media.matches);
    }
    const listener = () => setMatches(media.matches);
    window.addEventListener("resize", listener);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", listener);
  }, [matches, query]);

  return matches;
}

export default useMediaQuery;
```